# how to customize this my bash script code?

Tags: bash

i have this result:

```
user@zero:~/Desktop$ cat file.txt
      1 127.0.0.1
      1 136.250.56.47
      1 192.168.1.1
      1 217.125.42.28
      1 51.83.239.142
      1 74.125.133.188
      1 84.47.125.229
     28 45.77.234.35
     30 45.25.36.25
     43 0.0.0.0
```

i want to get ip addresess that repeated 
I'm going to identify IP addresses that have been repeated over 40 times. For example, in this output, IPs that are repeated 30 times are as follows:

```
45.25.36.25
```

how i can doing this job?

Comment: what (coding) have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gawk '{ if ($1 > 40) print $2}' file.txt
```

This says, for every line (`{}`) in `file.txt`, if the first space-delimited field (`$1`) is greater than 40, print the second space-delimited field.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through awk

```
cat <<EOF | awk '$1 > 28 {print $2}'
      1 127.0.0.1
      1 136.250.56.47
      1 192.168.1.1
      1 217.125.42.28
      1 51.83.239.142
      1 74.125.133.188
      1 84.47.125.229
     28 45.77.234.35
     30 45.25.36.25
     43 0.0.0.0
EOF
```

or, for your case

`awk '$1 > 28 {print $2}' file.txt`